# Loading .obj file with OBJMTLLoader.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, loader, .obj

In Three.js I'm using OBJMTLLoader.js to load my 3D model.

After Chrome has loaded the scene, the model is not shown. In the console I have >60'000 warnings. They all look like:

```
THREE.OBJMTLLoader: Unhandled line f -215//-215 -202//-202 -212//-212
```

When I use OBJLoader.js to load the model (without the .mtl file), the model gets loaded successfully (of course without materials)

**What is the problem with the OBJMTLLoader.js loader?**

This is how I load the model:

```
<script src="scripts/objmtlloader.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/DDSLoader.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/MTLLoader.js"></script>
```

...

```
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();    
loader.load(objFileName, mtlFileName, function(object) {
    scene.add(object);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your model can be loaded in other .obj loaders. Those numbers are indexes to faces, so they should not be negative.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the model gets loaded - even looks quite pretty! Do you mean changing to positive numbers would fix the problem?

Comment: Negative indices in OBJ are indices relative to the last vertex added (at that point in the file). They are a pain, and unsupported by many OBJ readers.

Comment: Btw. I checked the code of OBJLoader, in that loader negative indices are handled: var face_pattern4 = /f( +(-?\d+)\/\/(-?\d+))( +(-?\d+)\/\/(-?\d+))( +(-?\d+)\/\/(-?\d+))( +(-?\d+)\/\/(-?\d+))?/